# Durandal, Breeze, and DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, breeze, durandal

### I am developing a SPA as a DotNetNuke module. Everything works well, but I can't find a way to make the module work with Breeze. The DNN version i am using is 7.04, which is I think the latest. DNN uses its own WebApi (written on top of WebApi) and the modules have no AppStart folder.

I added this part after some thought

In DNN you can add a route like so:

```
public class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
{
    public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
    {
        mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("MyModuleName", "default", "{controller}/{action}",
        new[] { "MyModule.NameSpace" });
        //Second route....
        //third rout.....
    }
}
```

Breeze on the other hand register the route on AppStart using the WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod.

It seems to me that all I need to do is to add a route to the code above and just refer to Breeze as another DNN Module like so

```
mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("BreezeApi,"Breeze", "api/{controller}/{action}...
```

But according to the comments on breeze's startup class, breeze route should be inserted at the front of ALL api route so I suspect it won't work. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to develop a new module? You can create your own folder in the new module

Comment: Just an FYI, latest release is 7.0.5 but that shouldn't really matter for what you are doing

Comment: I am interested in using Breeze in my PhoneGap Mobile app (onto my DNN website) - I am currently not using it and making normal DNN Controller calls with Peta Poco

Comment: Did you get this working? I am pretty much stuck at the same point - I added the BreezeController attribute and I can get back a list of objects but filtering with URL params does not work. I think this is because the Breeze controller is not running before my request (as in the Breeze Sample)

Comment: ps - this seems to be the pertinent info - http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-routing

Comment: Interestingly, this class does actually fire if you debug it - BreezeWebApiConfig.cs - it just doesn't seem to work

Comment: Responding to your same question elsewhere on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045327/controller-not-filtering-data-in-breeze-query-in-dotnetnuke-module

Comment: @Rodney I have just got back to the problem and I think I have a solution, I will update this post as soon as I am done testing

Comment: Thanks David, I have set up a public service on my post above

Comment: Hi David, I need to make a call on whether to go down the Breeze route or DTO route - any joy on this?

Comment: Please see my reply to this S.O.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045327/controller-not-filtering-data-in-breeze-query-in-dotnetnuke-module

Comment: Yip, Ward has posted there with a solution to the issues I was having - it should solve this problem