# Controller not filtering data in Breeze query in DotNetNuke Module

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke, breeze

I am trying to include the basic Breeze sample in a DotNetNuke module (it works fine in a standalone WebAPI project). To simplify things I remove the client and will just refer to the URL JSON calls I make in the Chrome browser.

I can see my metadata and a full list of items, eg: 
http://www.dnndev.me/DesktopModules/framework/api/breeze/dare/metadata
http://www.dnndev.me/DesktopModules/framework/api/breeze/dare/todos

however, when I try to filter the list from the URL, it always returns the full list, e.g.
http://www.dnndev.me/DesktopModules/framework/api/breeze/dare/todos?=DareId%20eq%204

I think it is something to do with the way I have declared the MapHTTRoute. The problem is that DotNetNuke modules do not have a Global.ascx. I have copied the BreezeWebApiconfig.cs file into my App_Start folder and this does fire when I debug, however DotNetNuke uses mechanism for registering routes:

```cs
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;

namespace SmartThinker.Modules.Framework
{
    public class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
    {
        public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
        {
            mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("framework", "BreezeApi", "breeze/{controller}/{action}", new[] { "SmartThinker.Modules.Framework.Controllers" });
        }
    }
}
```

I have read up on http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller#note01 and http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-routing but it seems that it's something to do with the way DNN registers the routes. Is there anyway to do this without using BreezeWebApiConfig.cs?

My controller code has the BreezeController attribute. (When I do connect the sample client to it I do get a list of items - it just does not filter, so I think it is something to with the OData Action filters. How can I debug where the problem is?

**Update 1)** 
Here is the metadata:
http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/metadata

The GetUsers method:
http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/getusers

and the GetUsers method trying to filter by UserID (which doesn't work, which is the issue)
http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/getusers?=UserID%20eq%204
http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/GetUsersWithoutCors?=UserID%20eq%204  (this returns IQueryable)

Here is the controller:

```cs
[BreezeController]
public class DareController : DnnApiController
{
    private readonly EFContextProvider<FrameworkContext> contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<FrameworkContext>();

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Metadata()
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, contextProvider.Metadata());
        return GetResponseWithCorsHeader(response);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetUsers()
    {
        var userInfoController = new UserInfoController();

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, userInfoController.GetUsers());
        return GetResponseWithCorsHeader(response);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<User> GetUsersWithoutCors()
    {
        return contextProvider.Context.Users;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The routing is not really a Breeze issue. How your server routes requests to your controller is up to you. What we do out-of-the-box is just one way among innumerable many.

You have the `[BreezeController]` attribute on your controller yes? Can you put a sample endpoint up where we could hit it. Might get some clues from that. Also post the controller. A tiny example should do ... something returning metadata and one method returning IQueryable.

## Update 25 Jun 2013

**I think you've discovered a bug in the way our `[BreezeController]` discovers methods returning `IQueryable<T>`**.

The `[BreezeController]` attribute scans your Web API controller methods and (in effect) applies the `[BreezeQueryable]` attribute to methods returning `IQueryable<T>`.

> `[BreezeQueryable]` is an extension of the Web API's `[Queryable]` that adds support for $select, $expand, and nested $orderby ... all missing from the current `[Queryable]`.

I see now that your `GetUsers()` method returns `HttpResponseMessage` rather than `IQueryable<User>`. Let's assume that the `userInfoController.GetUsers()` method inside your method returns `IQueryable<User>`. Otherwise, the OData query parameters will not apply and we'll have to take this in a different direction.  Moving along ...

I checked with v.1.3.6 of the Breeze.WebApi.dll and it does not detect that the `HttpResponseMessage` is wrapping `IQueryable<T>`. Therefore, it does not apply the client's OData query criteria (or any other OData modifiers for that matter). This shortcoming (in my opinion) is a bug. The following should be equivalent implementations:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<TodoItem> Todos() {
    return _repository.Todos;
}

[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage TodosWrapped()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _repository.Todos);
}
```

The second, "wrapped" method does not respect the OData query parameters.

Fortunately, there is a workaround until we get this fixed. Just add the `[BreezeQueryable]` attribute explicitly ... as in:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[BreezeQueryable]
public HttpResponseMessage TodosWrapped()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _repository.Todos);
}
```

I confirmed that this approach **does** work.

Thanks for finding this.

#### Use OData query syntax

A colleague also noticed that your query URL does not use the OData query syntax. You wrote:

```
... /todos?=DareId%20eq%204
```

when it should be

```
... /todos/?$filter=DareId%20eq%204
```

Make sure you use `?$filter=`

Comment: Thank's Ward, I will put this together tonight and post it up!

Comment: Ok, here is the public webApi: 1) The MetaData http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/metadata  the Get Users method - http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/getusers and then here is what doesn't work - trying to filter it on UserID - http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/getusers?=UserID%20eq%204

Comment: I have updated my original post with the controller and some live services. I think it has something to do with registering of the routes.

Comment: Hi Ward, I put up the endpoint above - please let me know if you can spot where I might be going wrong - thanks

Comment: Out-of-town until next week, Rodney. Maybe someone else can handle in the meanwhile. Sorry

Comment: Excellent, that works in my basic test. I will go over this in more detail in the next few days, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Ward, I have a problem with adding Queryable to the methods that return an HTTPResponseMessage, it throws this exception:  http://www.ftter.com/desktopmodules/framework/api/dare/GetUsers?$filter=Username%20eq%20'berty'  "cannot support querying. Ensure the type of the returned content is IEnumerable, IQueryable, or a generic form of either interface". Users is a DB Set (public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; })

Comment: The bottom method (that returns IQueryable) works but the bottom one does not:                   [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        [Queryable]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetUsers()
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, contextProvider.Context.Users);
            return ControllerUtilities.GetResponseWithCorsHeader(response);
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        [Queryable]
        public IQueryable<User> GetUsersWithoutCors()
        {
            return contextProvider.Context.Users;
        }

Comment: I found a solution by casting the return value - this works - thanks:          [Queryable]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetUsers()
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, (IQueryable<User>)contextProvider.Context.Users);
            return ControllerUtilities.GetResponseWithCorsHeader(response);
        }

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I wonder if the exception came from breeze or web API. Substituting [queryable] for [BreezeQueryable] would reveal the answer quickly.

Comment: Using [BreezeQueryable] works without a casting. using [Queryable] throws the exception (unless I cast it). So which one do you recommend?

Comment: Actually, I spoke to soon. [BreezeQueryable] does not throw an exception but the return resultset does not filter with the Filter querystring param. As soon as I add the cast and switch it to [Queryable] then the exact same URL filters it.

Comment: Hi Ward, please have a read of this issue - I think there are some more issues with it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475435/how-to-use-breeze-iqueryable-with-cors

Comment: Too many issues in the air at this point. You'll find my thoughts on your CORS issue over on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475435/how-to-use-breeze-iqueryable-with-cors/17479498#17479498 I tried adding `[BreezeQueryable]` explictly to the method of one of my sample and it works for me (including $select and $expand). If you think `[BreezeQueryable]` is not working, please start a new SO on that topic and provide a small sample to demonstrate the failure. Thx

Comment: Ok ... hold on. Too many issues as I said. I missed the combination of `[BreezeQueryable]` and the method returning `HttpResponseMessage`. That seems not to work. I'll file a report on it.

Comment: Agreed, I went down so many routes and seemed to be barking up the wrong tree with the EF CodeFirst/Model first - I now think it is all related to BreezeQueryable/IQueryable etc. If I can find a better wat of doing CORS then I don't need to wrap it perhaps. Thanks for your help.